A leading term of the polynomials of a Gröbner basis divides the leading terms of the polynomials of the ideal
This is Exercise 5 in [1, Chapter 2]. The exercise states:

Let $I$ be an ideal in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$, where $k$ is a field. Show that $G=\{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}\subseteq I$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$ if and only if the leading term of every element of $I$ is divisible by one of the $\operatorname{lt}(g_i)$.

The notation $\operatorname{lt}(g_i)$ refers to the leading term of the polynomial $g_i$ with respect to a monomial ordering.
I've been able to prove the converse. I want to show that if $\{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}$ is a Gröbner basis for $I$ and $f\in I$, then $\operatorname{lt}(f)$ is divisible by one of $\operatorname{lt}(g_i)$. The fact that $\{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}$ is a Gröbner basis implies that for every $f\in I$
$$\operatorname{lt}(f) = a_1 \operatorname{lt}(g_1) + \ldots + a_t \operatorname{lt}(g_t),$$
for some $a_1, \ldots a_t\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_t]$.
By dividing $\operatorname{lt}(f)$ by $\operatorname{lt}(g_i)$ (one at a time), we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{lt}(f) ={}& b_1 \operatorname{lt}(g_1) + r_1 \\
{}={}&b_2 \operatorname{lt}(g_2) + r_2
\\
\vdots\,\,&\\
{}={}&b_t \operatorname{lt}(g_t) + r_t,
\end{aligned}$$
and either $r_i=0$ or $\operatorname{lt}(g_i)$ does not divide any of the terms of $r_i$. We want to show that at least one of $r_i$ must be zero.
One observation is that $r_i \in \langle \operatorname{lt}(g_1), \ldots, \operatorname{lt}(g_t)\rangle$, which is a monomial ideal, which means that $r_i$ is divisible by one $\operatorname{lt}(g_j)$; say $r_i = c_{i} \operatorname{lt}(g_{j(i)})$, for some $c_i\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.
In other words,
$$\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{lt}(f) {}={} a_1 \operatorname{lt}(g_1) + \ldots + a_t \operatorname{lt}(g_t) {}={}& b_1 \operatorname{lt}(g_1) + c_1 \operatorname{lt}(g_{j_1}) \\
{}={}&b_2 \operatorname{lt}(g_2) + c_2 \operatorname{lt}(g_{j_2})
\\
\vdots\,\,&\\
{}={}&b_t \operatorname{lt}(g_t) + c_t \operatorname{lt}(g_{j_t}).
\end{aligned}$$
I'm stuck at this point and I would appreciate any help.
[1]: David A. Cox, John Little, Donal O'Shea, Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms: An Introduction to Computational Algebraic Geometry and Commutative Algebra, Springer, 2015

What do you know about monomial ideals?  One fact which would be useful here: if $h_1, \ldots, h_t$ are monomials, then $\langle h_1, \ldots, h_t \rangle$ is precisely the set of $f$ such that every monomial term in $f$ is divisible by one of the $h_i$.

@DanielSchepler Thanks a lot! The penny dropped!

@PantelisSopasakis Hi, I'm interested in the full demonstration. Could you provide it to me please? thanks in advance

@Richy65, sure I'll provide a full answer

$\newcommand{\LT}{\operatorname{lt}}\newcommand{\<}{\langle}\newcommand{\>}{\rangle}\newcommand{\N}{{\rm I\!N}}$Credit goes to @DanielSchepler (see their comment above). I'm providing a solution here just for the sake of clarity.
Hereafter, we will denote the leading term of $f\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ by $\LT(f)$.
Firstly, we need this proposition:

Proposition 1. Let $I = \<x^\alpha; \alpha \in A\>$ be a monomial ideal. Then, $x^\beta\in I$ iff $x^\beta$ is divisible by $x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in A.$

Proof. Firstly, the easy part: suppose $x^\beta$ is divisible by $x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in A,$ i.e., there is $\gamma\in\N^n$ such that $x^\alpha x^\gamma = x^\beta$, and trivially $x^\gamma\in I$.
For the converse, suppose $x^\beta\in I$. This means that there are $h_1, \ldots, h_s\in k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ such that
$$\underbrace{h_1x^{\alpha_1} + \ldots + h_s x^{\alpha_s}}_{\text{polynomial}} = \underbrace{{}\;\;{}x^\beta{}\;\;{}}_{\text{monomial}}.\tag{$*$}$$
The trick here is that on the lhs we have a polynomial (what seems to be a general polynomial), but on the right we have a monomial, so $h_1x^{\alpha_1} + \ldots + h_s x^{\alpha_s}$ is a monomial! Suppose
$$h_i = \sum_{j=1}^{M}\kappa_{j}^{i}x^{\lambda_{j}^{i}},$$
for all $i=1,\ldots, s$, where $\kappa^i_j \in k$ and $\lambda_{j}^{i}\in\N^n$. Then, from ($*$) we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{s}\sum_{j=1}^{M}\kappa_{j}^{i}x^{\lambda_{j}^{i}+\alpha_i} = x^\beta,$$
and because the thing on the lhs is a monomial, there is an $i^*$ such that
$$\beta = \alpha_{i^*} + \text{something},$$
so that $x^{\alpha_{i^*}} {}\mid{} x^\beta$. $\Box$
We can now prove this proposition:

Proposition 2. Let $I$ be an ideal in $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$. Show that $G=\{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}\subseteq I$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$ if and only if the leading term of every element of $I$ is divisible by one of $\LT(g_i)$.

Proof. (1) Suppose that $G=\{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}$ is a Gröbner basis of $I$ and $f\in I$. We want to show that $\LT(f)$ is divisible by one of $\LT(g_i)$. The fact that $\{g_1, \ldots, g_t\}$ is a Gröbner basis implies that
$$\LT(f) = a_1 \LT(g_1) + \ldots + a_t \LT(g_t),$$
This means that $\LT(f) \in \<\LT(g_1), \ldots, \LT(g_t)\>$ and the latter is a monomial ideal, so from Proposition 1 it is divisible by one of $\LT(g_i)$.
(2) For the converse, suppose that for every $f\in I$, $\LT(f)$ is divisible by an $\LT(g_i)$.
To show that $G$ is a Gröbner basis, we need to show that $\<\LT(I)\> = \<\LT(g_1), \ldots, \LT(g_t)\>$. It suffices to show that $\<\LT(I)\> \subseteq \<\LT(g_1), \ldots, \LT(g_t)\>$.
Let $f$ be such that $\LT(f)\in \<\LT(I)\>$. This means
$$\begin{align}
\LT(f) ={}& a_1 \LT(f_1) + \ldots + a_m \LT(f_m) 
\\
={}& a_1h_1\LT(g_1) + \ldots + a_m h_m \LT(g_m) 
\\
{}\in{}& \<\LT(g_1), \ldots, \LT(g_m)\>
\end{align}$$
This completes the proof. $\Box$
